# How to show this conclusion which concerns two distribution functions?

Tags: integration, expected-value, inverse-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

If $F$ and $G$ are two distribution functions, how to prove that $$\int_{0}^{1} \lvert F^{-1}(t)-G^{-1}(t)\rvert dt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\lvert F(x)-G(x)\rvert dx$$ with $$F^{-1}(p)=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R},F(x)\geq p\}$$ I have no idea to deal with the integral of the absolute value of the difference of two distribution functions. The left side is in fact equal to $\mathbb{E}[\lvert F^{-1}(U)-G^{-1}(U)\rvert]$ where $U$ is in the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.\
This is an important exercice in my course and I really need someone who can help me solve it.

Comment: Sketch the corresponding areas as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this question under his help.

Let $\Phi(x,t)=\mathbb{1}_{\{F(x)\geq G(x),t\in [G(x),F(x)]\}}+\mathbb{1}_{\{F(x)<G(x),t\in [F(x),G(x)]\}}$, then we have $$\lvert F(x)-G(x)\rvert=\int_{0}^{1}\Phi(x,t)dt$$
so using the Fubini's theorem, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\lvert F(x)-G(x)\rvert dx&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^1 \Phi(x,t)dtdx\\
&=\int_0^1(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi(x,t) dx)dt\\
&=\int_0^1\lvert F^{-1}(t)-G^{-1}(t)\rvert dt
\end{split}
\end{equation}
because $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi(x,t) dx=\lvert F^{-1}(t)-G^{-1}(t)\rvert,\forall t\in[0,1]$$

Is it correct? I want to ask if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to express $|F(x) - G(x)|$ as $\int 1_{(F(x),G(x))} (t)dt$ then you just make use of Fubini theorem

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just solved this problem.